# Showing a function is uniformly continuous by using the derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, uniform-continuity

Let $f(x) = \sqrt x \cos\frac{1}{x}$. Show $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(0, \infty)$.

Now as I recall, we've learned in class that if $f'(x)$ is bounded therefore $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Indeed,
$$ f'(x) = ... = \frac{1}{\sqrt x} \left( \frac{1}{2}\cos\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x} + \sin\frac{1}{x} \right) $$

Boundesness:
$$\left|f'(x)\right| = \frac{1}{\sqrt x} \left( \frac{1}{2} \left|\cos\frac{1}{x}\right|  + \frac{1}{x} \left|\frac{1}{x}\right| \right) \le \frac{1}{\sqrt x}(\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{x}) \le \frac{3}{2}$$

**My Question:**
Is this sufficent? Because I've seen a solution for this excersise which using another approach:

By Cantor's theorem the funciton is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$
And for $(1, \infty)$ we are showing $f$ is Lipschitz (and then proving uniform continuous directly by definition)

Isn't it useless if you can just claim $f$ is uniformly continuous by the derivative boundesness? Or am I wrong and my simple proof falls somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not good. Why would $$\frac{1}{\sqrt x}(\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{x}) \le \frac{3}{2}$$ be even remotely true? For small values of $x$, the statement is completely false...

Comment: Oh, this claim is true for $x\ge 1$ and this is why we want to split into cases. Right?

Comment: For $x\geq 1$, the statement is true. This means that the function is uniformly continuous at least for $x\geq 1$.